# Edit NSLayoutConstraint created with visual format

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I am working on custom NSView.
In that view I am using autolayout and visual format to set it up.
The code would be something like:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[label1]-[label2]-[label3]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

My problem is that at some point I would like to modify previous constraint adding extra field.
How could I achieve that?
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[label1]-[label2]-[label3]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

It returns an array of constraints.  You could hold onto those and then at the appropriate time, you could remove them and re-add new ones.

Comment: I have logged the output of constrainsWithVisualFormat and it is something like:

`2016-03-07 22:18:00.634 App[29041:542725] create constraint (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fde4ec22360 V:|-(0)-[NSButton:0x7fde4b2d38a0'Button']   (Names: '|':NSView:0x7fde4e39feb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fde4ec223b0 V:[NSButton:0x7fde4b2d38a0'Button']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x7fde4e39feb0 )>"
)
)`

If I want to modify this, is it enough if I just clear the array and call constrainsWithVisualFormat again or I must edit the array entry?

Comment: You have to loop through the constraints and remove them from the view.  Then create a new array.